# What do you file as the form number you filled last year if you amended it?

Tags: united-states, income-tax, form-1040x, form-1040

Last year, I accidentally filled Form-1040 first, then I realized that I need to file 1040NR-EZ. So I filled 1040X and 1040NR-EZ last year itself.

Now I was filling the 1040NR form this year and there is a question in it "Did you file a U.S. income tax return for any prior year? If “Yes,” give the latest year and form number you filed"

How should I answer that question? Should I say 2017 Form 1040NR-EZ? or 1040X or 1040?

Comment: Did you get any refund or notices based on the 1040NR-EZ that you filed to show that it was accepted? My inclination is that generally with the IRS you go with the corrected fact, but it may depend in this case on whether the 1040NR-EZ was accepted.